# Change the background effect in Launchpad on Yosemite

Tags: macos, launchpad

In Mavericks I learned that the keyboard combination control+option+command+B would allow the user to cycle through the various background effects (blur, no blur, black and white, etc.). However, this keyboard combination doesn't appear to have any effect in OS X 10.10 Yosemite. Is there a way for the user to accomplish this task in Yosemite?

System: Mac mini, late 2012 running OS X 10.10 with the Apple Wireless Keyboard

Comment: the control+option+command+B does not work on my Mavericks?

Comment: Buscar, does command+B work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Previous versions of OS X had ways to disable this, but starting in OS X 10.10, you can't. The launcher, login screen, and mission control all have blurry backgrounds, it looks hideous, and you are stuck with it.